# find -exec not working properly, why?

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to list all the file names (the basename, not the full path) below my home directory using find. I tried to do:

```
find ~/ -type f -exec echo $(basename "{}") ";"
```

However I end up having a list of full paths, and not only of the basenames as I would like. I now use `echo`, but ideally the result of `$(basename "{}")` should be the argument of some other function I want to write.

Why is the basename function not applied correctly?

Comment: actually this was on stackoverflow.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627446/find-and-basename-not-playing-nicely sorry for the redundant post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell is interpreting the `$(...)` before it runs `find`. If you want the find shell to execute it instead, you'll need to stop bash substituting it. We can do that like so:

```
find ~/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo $(basename "{}")' \;
```

The key here are the single quotes; Bash won't touch anything inside those.

Comment: thanks!  the best explanation I found (I didn't know the difference between single and double quotes, and showing it in debug mode really made the difference for me): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428628/find-whats-up-with-basename-and-dirname